# Find the original file for a series of soft-linked files

Tags: linux, bash, function, shell, symlink

How would I write a bash shell script that finds the original file for a series of soft-linked files? 
For example, if I had 5 files in a directory and named file1 through file5. File2 is linked to file1, file3 is linked to file2, file4 is linked to file3, and file5 is liked to file4. In this case, the original file is file1.

I want the script to search for the file in the current directory, not providing the path.

If there is no symlink then display message saying so

if there is a symlink then should display the original file, and names of the symlinked files:
eg
file is file1. Symlinked files are: file2, file3, file4. file5.

Comment: Did you try to solve it yourself?

Comment: Use "ls -l" and it will show you symlinks.

Answer (score -1):

```
for f in *
  do test -L $f || echo $f ;
done
```

Comment: "test -L" works perfectly well.  If the answer is not scrupulously complete, it is because I leave a bit for the questioner to think about so I'm not doing their homework.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: ?? It does as I -- even now -- read his question.  He has several files in a directory and wants to know which are symlinks and which are not.  He asked that quite clearly to me.  Otherwise, then, "man readlink" is the answer.

Comment: He doesn't *only* want to know which are symlinks, he also wants to know where they point to.  Your first comment says that the answer is not complete - and that very clearly means that this is not the correct answer to the question.  Giving hints is fine, but it should be in comments, not answers.